# Need to escape the json

Tags: javascript, php, json, wordpress, magic-quotes-gpc

i have situation i am getting this array from post

```
Array([0] => {"question":"test  " jakce"}
)
```

i need to escape the string  :

```
Array([0] => {"question":"test  \" jakce"}
)
```

i already try addslash php method it just add slash to everywhere i just need the slash in middle of string "test  \" jakce" , also need to escape anystring like contains single quotes double quotes etc.

Thanks.

Comment: Why is the slash not in there in the first place? You cannot correctly escape strings after the fact, if that were possible we wouldn't need escaping. You really need to transmit the data correctly in the first place.

Comment: Thanks Deceze for reply actually i saved the data wordpress post meta with json.strnigfy method , the problem is when i send the data by $post all the slashes removed , i don't why this happen.

Comment: You mention you used `json.stringify`. This is javascript. Please tag your question with javascript, as you seem to be encoding incorrectly, as @deceze said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have solved my issue , my issue with wordpress post meta it is server side problem not with javascript , i used the $_POST but it should be $_REQUEST method

if you are also get parsing problem with Json in wordpress post meta , try to use the $_REQUEST instead of $_POST

Hope it will help someone else too.

Thank You all.

Comment: So Wordpress incorrectly/overzealously sanitizes `$_POST`? Not that I'm terribly surprised; but you'd think they'd offer some specific provisions for POSTing JSON.